# Corda 4.0 transaction serialization issue

Tags: corda

Having recently upgraded to Corda 4.0 we are now seeing a serialization exception when trying to create transactions:

> [ERROR] 10:09:49,500 [Mock network] amqp.SerializationOutput. -
>   Serialization failed direction="Serialize",
>   type="net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction",
>   msg="Defined getter for parameter commands returns type
>   java.util.List> yet underlying
>   type is java.util.List>",
>   ClassChain="net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction"
>   {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=Supplier 1,
>   L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000001,
>   flow-id=e61b7da7-6826-4410-9414-1c03bebbc3fe,
>   invocation_id=58c5f5ff-09f8-4bfa-bbe5-cf6b0ef47d06,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-03-28T10:09:46.205Z, origin=Only For
>   Testing, session_id=58c5f5ff-09f8-4bfa-bbe5-cf6b0ef47d06,
>   session_timestamp=2019-03-28T10:09:46.205Z, thread-id=400}

Any ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see an error message of this form on Corda 4:

> Defined getter for parameter [parameter name] returns type [type] yet
>   underlying type is [exactly the same type]

It's caused by a bug in certain versions of Guava.

Corda 4 uses Guava version `25.1-jre`. However, if your node loads another version of Guava (e.g. `21.0`) that overrides Corda's version of Java, you will see this error.

A fix is planned for Corda 4.1.

Comment: I get a similar same error in corda 4.3. I tried filtered transactions for my cordapp using an oracle,it works fine. But if I use send or sendAndReceive after signing the tx with oracle. I am getting .... 
 
Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", type="java.util.List", msg="Described type with descriptor net.corda:1f2tmsdgsu106jed1w0vJw== was expected to be of type interface java.util.List but was class com.insurance.state.MyState"  
 
This happens only if i use and oracle to sign the transaction. If i dont use and oracle. I am not getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well after upgrade to 4.0. My flows returned transaction as output and I've got TraversableTransaction serialization exception. I didn't solved it. I've created flow response DTO with all appropriated data, trxId etc...

Example:

```
SignedTransaction signedTransaction = subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTx, session));
response.setTrxId(signedTransaction.getId().toString());
return response;
```